# Linq Multiple OR with a list

Tags: c#, sql, linq, list

I'm currently working on a C# project where I'm using LINQ.
I was wondering if it was possible to make a "multiple OR clause" with Linq with a list as an entry for the where.

I mean something like that:

```
var listofId;

var sqlQuery = from T in mytable 
               where T.ReferenceId = listOfId 
               select T;
```

Any idea about how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx)

```
listOfId.Contains(T.ReferenceId);
```